# Trying to Lay New Trim Straight

Tags: trim

I removed an old piece of trim that was installed cockeyed by someone else. It was a 1"x6" board that ran across and was nailed to shiplap wood behind it. The problem is that it was about 1/2" proud of the above drywall on the left side, but was flush with the drywall on the right side. How can I attach new trim so that it's nice and even all the way through? I was going to get some trim that goes up and covers the bottom of the drywall, but my concern is that when I nail the bottom of the trim to the wood, it will be angled if I don't put wood directly behind it. I've provided some pictures to show what it looks like both with and without the 1x6 board.

With board:
[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Without board:
[image: Image 3]

[image: Image 4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do is shim the studs that the baseboard is nailed to.

If the difference is 1/2" then add a 1/2" piece of wood to the stud on the right side of the picture.  Use a straight edge from the newly shimmed stud to the stud on the far left, measure and install shims to the studs in between to get out the same distance.  I can't tell what the wood is that is behind the baseboard - I can see some studs.  You don't need to shim all the wood just every 16" ( standard spacing for studs ) and just mark the floor so you know where to nail.

If the distance is fractional you can do other things like take wood screws with flat heads and use those to hold the baseboard off the surface of the studs.  You probably want two screws so the baseboard is held off in a reasonably firm way - one at maybe 1/4" shy of the top and one 1/4" shy of the bottom ( just choose a height that you can avoid when you trim nail the baseboard to the studs ).

It looks like you are re-doing your flooring.  Put the baseboards on after the flooring.

Comment: Really helpful and easy to understand answer. Thanks!